# Sup, Inf, max and min of a given set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For a given set $$M_1 =  \left\lbrace \frac{2-(-1)^{n}}{n}; n \in \mathbb{N} \right\rbrace. $$

Determine if it is bounded? Determine inf and sup, and if they exist max and min.

My first concern is if $n = 0$, we have an undefined value in the set, what does this mean for min, max, inf and sup?

If I continue without this concern I determine $\max = 3 $, when $ n=1 $ since the given number will be decreasing as $n$ increases.

My guess for $\min$ is that it does not exist, since the series will be approaching 0 as $n \to \infty $.

Should $\inf = 0$ suffice as an answer? How can I motivate this?

I am unsure as how to choose $\sup$ since it would need to be larger than 3, but can I choose any number larger? How can I motivate it?

Please take into account the level I am at, I am taking my second semester of maths at university and we have just started with the definition of limits and sup/inf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My first concern is if $n = 0$, we have an undefined value in the set,
>   what does this mean for min, max, inf and sup?

While there is no consensus, it is fairly usual to write $\mathbb N$ to mean the set $\{1,2,3,4\dots\}$, in other words, $0\notin\mathbb N$.

---

> If I continue without this concern I determine $\max = 3 $, when $ n=1 $ since the given number will be decreasing as $n$ increases.

While $\max=3$ is the correct answer, your reasoning is incorrect. The given number is not decreasing as $n$ increases. When you go from $n=2$ to $n=3$, the number does not decrease. It goes from $\frac{2-1}{2}=\frac12$ to $\frac{2+1}{3}=1$, so it increases!

---

> My guess for $\min$ is that it does not exist, since the series will be approaching 0 as $n \to \infty $.

Again, your guess is correct, but the reasoning is not. True, the series approaches $0$ as $n\to \infty$, but that is not enough to conclude that the minimum does not exist. For example, the series $$0, 1, \frac12, \frac13,\frac14,\frac15,\dots$$ also approaches $0$ as $n\to\infty$, but the set of its elements **does** have a minimum!

---

> Should $\inf = 0$ suffice as an answer? How can I motivate this?

You can prove that $0$ is the infimum by proving

1. That $0$ is a lower bound
2. That for every $\epsilon > 0$, the value $0+\epsilon$ is **not** a lower bound.

---

> I am unsure as how to choose $\sup$ since it would need to be larger than 3, but can I choose any number larger? How can I motivate it?

If a set has a maximum element, then that element is always also the supremum. This is a very simple claim to prove rigorously, from the definition of supremum (it is great practice if you have the time!).

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! Could you clarify how one would correctly reason in order to determine that a min does not exist?

Comment: @JonLachmann Two possibilities. One, you can prove that $0$ is the infimum, and since $0$ is not in the set, the minimum cannot exist (if the minimum exists, it is equal to the infimum). Two, you can assume the minimum does exist, and try to arrive at a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You have got most of it right. When a set has  a maximum the maximum and supremum coincide. So the supremum is $3$ and the infimum is $0$. As far as your first question is concerned, $\mathbb N$ is the usual notation for $\{1,2,...\}$ and $0$ is not included.